# Input and output buffer on the serial port

Tags: .net, serial-port, buffer

I wrote a small program that writes on serial port.
I use SerialPort class (.NET Framework). When I write to serial port, immediately PortRecieved event was raised. Why program do that, when we know that serial port have input and output buffer. Write method writes to output buffer, read method reads from input buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check out the [`DataReceivedThreshold`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.receivedbytesthreshold.aspx) property.  It defines how many bytes will accumulate in the buffer before firing the `DataReceived` event, and defaults to 1.

See also this [Dev Center thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/4c70ddb5-0422-4b3c-9e2e-5462701902f0), which notes there may be some unexpected behavior with `DataReceivedThreshold` in some cases.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how many bytes will be accumulate in the buffer before firing event. It can be between 1 and 20 bytes. But I don't understand when program writes to the output buffer why event has triggered. Everything what program write to serial port (output) is recieved like input. For example, if program write "Test" on the output, input (using ReadExisting) method is same. Why?

Comment: @SilverDeveloper: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Perhaps you could post some sample code to clarify your problem?

Comment: Ok. First question - Serial port has input and output buffer. If program writes to serial port It writes to output buffer. If program reads from serial port it reads from input buffer. Is that correct?